# Should the verb after "Чтобы" be infinitive or in the past tense?

Tags: грамматика, синтаксис

When do I use an infinitive after Чтобы and when do I use the verb in the past?

This is confusing me when Чтобы is used to express the purpose of one action by another. I mean sentences like these:

*I woke up early to catch the train.*

*I woke up early so that we catch the train.*

I'm inclined to think that the absence of a subject in the subordinate clause after чтобы is why the infinitive is used. Maybe when the subject is clear from context?

*Я проснулся рано чтобы успеть на поезд.*

*Я проснулся рано чтобы мы успели на поезд.*

Are these sentences correct?

---

In other usages of Чтобы, things seem clearer to me:

*Скажи ему чтобы не переживал.*

*У меня нет времени чтобы играть.*

Are these correct?
Did I miss anything of relevance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All four sentences are correct, however for some of them better version exists stylistically-wise.

Subject is inferred from verbs' case. When you say `чтобы успеть`, subject is  you unless stated otherwise `чтобы ему успеть`, when you said `чтобы успел`, subject is not you unless stated explicitly `чтобы я успел`.

Comment: but what do you mean by your example: "чтобы ему успеть"? 
I can't see how it's relevant.

Comment: `надо срочно выезжать, чтобы ему успеть на самолёт`

Comment: does that mean the same thing as: "чтобы он успел на самолёт" ?!

Comment: Yes, it does!..